# Encode french character in Java over smpp?

Tags: java, smpp, jsmpp

This is my code i am tring to Send Message Over SMPP but as Output ? is coming:

```
public class Encoding 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketTimeoutException, AlreadyBoundException, VersionException, SMPPProtocolException, UnsupportedOperationException, IOException 
{
SubmitSM sm=new SubmitSM();
String strMessage="Pour se désinscrire du service TT ZONE, envoyez GRATUITEMENT « DTTZ » ";
String utf8 = new String(strMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"));
UCS2Encoding uc = UCS2Encoding.getInstance(true);
sm.setDataCoding(2);
sm.setMessageText(utf8);
System.out.println(sm.getMessageText());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
String strMessage="Pour se désinscrire du service TT ZONE, envoyez GRATUITEMENT « DTTZ » ";
String utf8 = new String(strMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Why do you do that *at all*? Since the `UCS2Encoding` class accepts a `String` as an argument, it will take care of the encoding itself.

Just do:

```
sm.setMessageText(strMessage);
```

---

As I mentioned in the other question you asked, you are mixing a LOT of concepts. Remind that a `String` is a sequence of `char`s; it is **independent of the encoding you use**. The fact that internally Java uses UTF-16 is totally irrelevant here. It could use UTF-32 or EBCDIC, or even use carrier pigeons, the process itself would not change:

```
                 encode           decode
String (char[]) --------> byte[] --------> String (char[])
```

And by using the `String` constructor taking a byte array as an argument, you *create a seqeunce of `char`s from these bytes using the default JVM encoding*. Which may, or may not, be UTF-8.

In particular, if you are using Windows, the default encoding will be windows-1252. Let us replace `encode` and `decode` above with the charset names. What you do is:

```
                 UTF-8           windows-1252
String (char[]) -------> byte[] --------------> String (char[])
```

"Houston, we have a problem!"

For more details, see the javadocs for `Charset`, `CharsetEncoder` and `CharsetDecoder`.